# how to make Prestashop 404 error pages redirected to homepage, and not to default template?

Tags: php, html, redirect, seo, prestashop

how to make Prestashop 404 error pages redirected to homepage, and not to default template?
i did try everything - nothing works.
i did put it in .htacess -> not working,
i placed it in 404.tpl file too, manual redirect with javascript in the head, sadly it dont accept the changes and it is not working.
i am not able to find where it is stated and from where it redirects 404 errors to this shitty template page.
from SEO stand of view this hurts really bad.
Please help me.
Thanks.

(been trying to fix this from 5 days now and i got to a dead end.
u are my only hope. Please help!)

Comment: Did you write in your `.htaccess` something like `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` ? Did you try `<?php header("Location: index.php");?>`?

Comment: where? in .htacess?

Comment: a php code in .htacess? is this possible?

Comment: i did try to put it in .htacesss - didnt work, it broke the ws.

Comment: In case you didnt know - redirecting 404s to the home page will make them soft 404's  https://www.seroundtable.com/301-pages-home-soft-404-22811.html

Comment: Did you check my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exacly know Prestashop but as I know you have similar class to:

```
class PageNotFoundControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'pagenotfound';
    public $page_name = 'pagenotfound';
    public $ssl = true;
    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content.
     *
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        header("Location: index.php") // delete everything here and add this line.
    }
```

Probably it is stored there:

> PrestaShop/controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php
>   [GitHub](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php)

As you can see you may add `header("Location index.php")` up there. In place `"Location <redirect_location>"` you can write where you want to redirect. More informations you can find in [PHP Manual: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: can you tell me exactly how to do it? - i mean where to paste it... in which file.

Comment: this all is in the file "/controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php"
sooo may be its the wrong file?

Comment: Check now, I think I found this file

Answer (score 0):

Create override in override/controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php with :

```
class PageNotFoundController extends PageNotFoundControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {   
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        Tools::redirect(__PS_BASE_URI__);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: does it matter where in the file i put it?

Comment: You got place in my answer.

Comment: thanks, let me try it , and ill type again to say what happened

Comment: there is no file "PageNotFoundController.php " in /override/controllers/front/ folder.
what to do? where to search for it?
there is the same file in /controllers/front/PageNotFoundController.php - is it the same file?

Comment: here is a part of the php code in that file:
class PageNotFoundControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'pagenotfound';
    public $page_name = 'pagenotfound';
    public $ssl = true;

Comment: public function initContent()
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header('Status: 404 Not Found');

        if (preg_match('/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$/i', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))) {
            $this->context->cookie->disallowWriting();
            if (!isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
                $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] = '';
                if (preg_match('@^'.__PS_BASE_URI__.'([0-9]+)\-([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?\.jpg$@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {

Comment: $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] = __PS_BASE_URI__.'p/'.Image::getImgFolderStatic($matches[0]).'/'.$matches[0].'-'.$matches[1].'.jpg';
                }
            }

Comment: there is nothing close to what you say above in the code that you suggested. I really cant figure it out . Thanks for the help really much.